# Cannot use Ctrl+D shortcut binding to Edit.RemoveRow

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

I am configuring the keyboard shortcuts.

After I press the Reset button, I can see that I am using Visual C# 2005 additional mapping sheme.

Then I am setting Ctrl+D as shortcut for Edit.RemoveRow.
[image]

After that I have used the "Press shortcut keys" textbox to get a list of every shortcut
that conflicts with Ctrl-D, some of them just starting with Ctrl-D as in the case of Ctrl-D, X.

Then I have removed every of those shortcuts as you see.

[image]

Now, nothing happens when I try Ctrl-D in a vb file.

Why is not the current row removed?

Comment: What are you actually expecting to happen? Do you think that that is going to erase a line of code? That's not a row so that's not what that action does. I'm not sure what it does without actually looking into it but the term "row" suggests a table or grid.

Comment: Ah, if you make an answer with the correct action name (Edit.LineDelete), I will accept it.

Comment: You should post your own answer. I didn't have all the required information and wasn't really interested in finding it, which is why I posted a comment instead. You found the information so you should post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct action name is actually Edit.LineDelete